# How to trigger change detection when array object is modified?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular4 app i have a component with a *ngFor directive based in a array:

```
 <div *ngFor="let person of persons">
   {{person.name}}
   {{person.car}}
 </div>
```

In the other part of the component im able to delete a car, so in the subscribe of the `deleteCar()` method i update the `persons` array to:

```
 deleteCar(car) {
   this.carService.deleteCar(car).subscribe(() =>  {
   this.persons.filter(obj => obj.car == car.name)
               .forEach(i => i.car = null);
   }
 }
```

The problem is that the *ngFor loop is not triggered when i modify a existing person object in the persons array. How to solve this?

Answer (score 15):

I solve it by destructuring the array. I'm not sure it's the best way to do it.

```
this.persons = [...this.persons];
```

As far as it will change the reference of the array, angular will notice that the array has been updated.

Comment: I find this still to be the way to trigger change detection with Angular 12 in 2021. Using .append() doesn't seem to work still. For small arrays it shouldn't be a major performance hit.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to achieve this is to have a behavior subject in a service and accesss it in you component.

So your service class may look like this

```
@Injectable()
export class PersonService {

private persons=  new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
public persons$ = this.persons.asObservable();//--> You can access this in your component

constructor() {
   //set the persons array here;
}

function deleteCar()//todo  

}
```

On the component

```
constructor(private personService: PersonService) {

}



ngOnInit() {
    this.persons= this.personService.persons$//Dont forget to do add the assync pipe or subscribe
}

delete(car){
    this.personService.deleteCar(car);
}
```

This Should work.

More info in -> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: won't it force angular to re-render the view after each change detection?

Comment: Yes, all components that use a the persons object from the persons service would be updated. Why would you not want to change your view if the object(state) of your application has changed? If it didn`t re-render you would be showing false information. Or a past state.

Comment: Depending on the size of your application you may consider using ngrx.